# Quick sort code doesn't work for sorted array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, quicksort

```
#include<stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b){
        int temp = *a;
        *a=*b;
        *b=temp;
}

int partition(int arr[], int l, int r){
        int pivot = arr[l];
        int left,right;
        for(left=l+1,right=r;left<right;){
            if(arr[left]>pivot && arr[right]<=pivot){
                    swap(&arr[left],&arr[right]);
            }
            if(arr[left]<=pivot)
                    left++;
            if(arr[right]>pivot)
                    right--;
    }
            swap(&arr[l],&arr[right]);
            return right;
}

    void quicksort(int arr[], int l, int r){
            int p;
        if (l < r){
                p = partition(arr,l,r);
                quicksort(arr,l,p-1);
                quicksort(arr,p+1,r);
        }
}

   int main(){
            int i,size;
    //      int arr[] = { 10, 20, 7 , 5, 24 , 17, 13, 56, 38, 12 , 29, 46};
    //      int arr[] = {0,2,2};
            int arr[] = {2,2,1,0};
            size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
            printf("The array before sorting is --->");
            for(i=0;i<size;i++){
                    printf("--->%d",arr[i]);
            }
            printf("--->END\n\n");
            quicksort(arr,0,size-1);
            printf("The array after sorting is --->");
            for(i=0;i<size;i++){
                    printf("--->%d",arr[i]);
            }
            printf("--->END");
    }
```

The quciksort code above works for an unsorted array but doesn't for sorted arrays. I tried altering partition function but to no avail. The swap in partition was removed for cases where the array is sorted but then it got broken for unsorted arrays.Can someone please help with this issue?

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `partition`, change the for loop to

```
for(left=l+1,right=r;left<=right;)
```

You missed the `=` sign, so one less comparison is taking place.

[Code](http://ideone.com/oWbONR).

Comment: I noticed that the code was sorting all but the first element of the array, which suggests this is likely to be the problem.